# Selenium + Python: How to click Pay button on Google Pay pop up iframe checkout?

Tags: python, selenium, iframe

UPDATED:

Here is the checkout link. Click on gPay Button, log in Google with gPay to see the final Pay button to complete order that I want Selenium script to click on.

https://store.ui.com/14391668/checkouts/ae284ed7a99abc227e54933f1760e670

---

I have Selenium script to got to checkout and click the gPay button that pops up a window iframe which has a Pay div button below. How can I switch to the iFrame and click the Pay button to complete checkout?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pubLj.png

Pay Button div

```
<div role="button" class="goog-inline-block jfk-button jfk-button-action b3-button b3id-button b3-ripple-container b3-primary-button" tabindex="0" style="user-select: none;" data-start-event-id="-131" data-was-visible="true">Pay<div class="b3id-ripple b3-ripple" aria-hidden="true" data-was-visible="true"></div></div>
```

This is the iframe in Body

```
<iframe style="border: 0px none; vertical-align: initial; display: block; width: 100%; position: static; top: auto; visibility: visible; z-index: auto; background-color: inherit; height: 510px; left: auto; min-height: auto; opacity: 1; transition: all 0s ease 0s;" src="https://payments.google.com/payments/u/0/embedded/buy_flow?tc=98%2C97%2C81%2C83%2xxxxxxxxxxxx" id="**sM432dIframe**" name="sM432dIframe" data-widget="current" title="" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I have tried these but did not work

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME, "sM432dIframe")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "goog-inline-block jfk-button jfk-button-action b3-button b3id-button b3-ripple-container b3-primary-button"))).click()
```

or

```
time.sleep(10)
driver.switch_to.frame("sM432dIframe")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "goog-inline-block jfk-button jfk-button-action b3-button b3id-button b3-ripple-container b3-primary-button"))).click()
```

Comment: See if this can help you [get inside iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74155111/accepting-cookies-with-selenium-cant-find-element/74155406#74155406)

Comment: Didn't work for me :(

Comment: Hello! Currently facing same issue, did you solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

In the `switch_to.frame()` function you need to specify the element thet contains the iframe. So instead of:

```
driver.switch_to.frame("sM432dIframe")
```

should be:

```
iframe = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'sM432dIframe') 
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

Comment: Tried this but it gave me this error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [id="sM432dIframe"]
Stacktrace:
RemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.sys.mjs:8:8
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:182:5
NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:394:5
element.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.sys.mjs:280:16
```

Comment: Here is the checkout link. Click on gPay Button, log in Google with gPay to see the final Pay button to complete order that I want Selenium script to click on.

https://store.ui.com/14391668/checkouts/ae284ed7a99abc227e54933f1760e670